# pem to PrivateKey without bouncycaslte

Tags: java, certificate, private-key, pem

I have the following bountycastle code and I need to switch it to use plain java only:

```
private PrivateKey getPrivateKeyFromCertificate(String certificate) throws Exception {
    PEMParser parser = new PEMParser(new StringReader(certificate));
    return new JcaPEMKeyConverter().getPrivateKey((PrivateKeyInfo) parser.readObject());
}
```

I tried this:

```
private PrivateKey getPrivateKeyFromCertificate(String certificate) throws Exception {
    String pemBase64 = certificate
            .replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
            .replaceAll("\r", "")
            .replaceAll("\n", "")
            .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", ""));
    byte[] pemData = Base64.decodeBase64(pemBase64);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pemData));
    return privateKey;
}
```

But I get the following error:
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid RSA private key

Comment: Curious that a file named `certificate.pem` contains a private key but not a certificate.

Comment: Does the data (file) contain a valid PEM private key block _preceded or followed by something (anything) else_? If so, you need to (identify and) remove all the something else(s), _as well as_ the header/trailer lines and linebreaks.

Comment: There's no file, it's a string saved in the DB. And yes, it does have the ---- BEGIN PRIVATE KEY ---  and as you see my code removed it, and still it doesn't work.

Comment: Sometimes people will place a header like `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` on a file that's of a different format thinking that will somehow make the file be interpreted a certain way. And sometimes Bouncycastle will ignore the header and correctly parse the file even if the format disagrees with the header. But Java's KeyFactory won't do that. In this example the data must be a proper PKCS8 format RSA private key. It's just a guess but I'll bet it's actually a PKCS1 format RSA private key.

Comment: Yeah, probably something like that happened, but I hoped that there is a code that will detect it (even if it's 20 lines instead of 2)...